# 2 hosted domains = 2 websites?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, multiple-domains

I have a website hosted by a company and would like to add another, separate, website to the same account. The company offers `2 hosted domains`, so does that mean this will be possible? I'm not sure what's meant by `2 hosted domains`. Does that mean I can have two websites or just two different domain names pointing at the one website? Thanks for any help.

Comment: A link to the hosting company in question may help us answer this for you

Comment: @John Conde - Sorry, wasn't sure if linking was encouraged, but it's [Namecheap's Value package](http://www.namecheap.com/web-hosting/shared-hosting.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two hosted domains would be two separate websites.